# Embed google apps in Microsoft Teams Tab getting error called "refuse to connect"

Tags: google-authentication, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have built an MS Teams application for the goggle classroom. When I embed that application in the MS Teams tab, I was able to get a login popup for login credentials. And then I was able to get the auth token from google for my account. And When I try to redirect to the google classroom page by creating a tab URL with the help MS Teams SDK javascript, it doesn't work.

```
function setGoogleClassRoom() {

            // This API tells Microsoft Teams to enable the 'Save' button. Since Microsoft Teams always assumes
            // an initial invalid state, without this call the 'Save' button will never be enabled.
            microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);

            microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler(function (saveEvent) {
                // Let the Microsoft Teams platform know what you want to load based on
                // what the user configured on this page
                microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
                    contentUrl: createTabUrl(), // Mandatory parameter
                    entityId: createTabUrl(), // Mandatory parameter
                    suggestedDisplayName: "Google Classroom",
                    websiteUrl: "https://classroom.google.com"
                });
                saveEvent.notifySuccess();
            });

        };


        function createTabUrl() {
            return `https://classroom.google.com`;
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Error Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Could you please share screen shot of the error?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT I have updated the questions with the screenshot.

Comment: Tabs support Iframable pages. Your page need to be iframable to display the page in tab. Could you please go through  the the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/add-tab#create-your-pages)

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT As I mentioned I am trying to load classroom.google.com inside the Teams tab, I don't think I would be able to set header options called Content-Security-Policy for google apps.
Could you please help me with this in detail?

Comment: Could you please try to add the URL in the valid domain?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT I also added that URL in the valid domains but google refused to connect as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: From the screenshots it looks like the page you are trying to load is not iframable. Could you please make sure the web page that you are trying to load meets the [tab requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/add-tab#create-your-pages).

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT
I am trying to load https://classroom.google.com/ inside the MS teams app by making a successful login.
And I don't think I will be able to add headers as mentioned in the tab requirements for the google pages. So I am looking for help to load those google classroom pages in MS Teams Tab.

Comment: Google does not allow to make pages iframable. Currently teams support only Iframable pages.